# Simon and Garfunkel - Song with Random Words

Tags: identify-this-song

Around 1997, I borrowed one of my parents' Simon and Garfunkel CDs (might of even been a cassette tape). It was pretty awesome and have lots of great songs on it.

There was one particular song, that I remember enjoying, that seemed like they were just naming a bunch of random things back to back. If I recall the song was pretty short (about a minute). I've searched google multiple times, but have not found the name of song, track or whatever it is. I started searching azlyrics, however it seems to of stopped serving my requests... not sure if it thinks I'm a bot because I clicked through a bunch of songs pretty quickly.

Anyway, if anyone knows the name of the song I'm referencing, or a good reference for me to find out, I would greatly appreciate it. I checked "The Break Up", "Old Friends" and "Silent Night (7 O'Clock News)". It is none of these. These have talking but they seem to be real talking. The song was more like "a rock; a bridge; running water..." but the list was longer and a bunch of things back to back. It may of actually be sung too, I'm not sure if there was instrumentals behind the talking and/or singing. I referenced the things above, which I think "rock" was mentioned, but not sure about the others. I always found *Bridge Over Troubled Water* when I've searched in the past, but that is not the song I'm looking for.

Comment: There's aren't many songs under 2 min in the the original Simon & Garfunkel discography, check their song list (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_recorded_by_Simon_%26_Garfunkel) and see if any title strikes a bell. For my self I couldn't identify a lyric that matches your description (random naming of things), Can you give some more details (specific words, song mood and tempo, etc.)?

Comment: @joseem, I looked at wikipedia after I posted this too and nothing there looked familiar. I'm curious if this was one of their fun side projects, kind of like how they did the old people song (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrzOwPdijxQ). The song I'm looking for was them talking though, and it seemed like just naming different things. When hearing it, I kept trying to correlate some sort of relationship between everything but couldn't. That actually made what they were saying interesting. Can't give too much info beyond that, as its been a long time since I've heard it.

Comment: So it was talking, not singing?  That's an important clue, you should edit it into the question.  Both "Old Friends" and "Silent Night (7 O'Clock News)" feature spoken word, but neither are Simon & Garfunkel talking (the later is a simulated newscast).

Comment: Just having done a search for "Simon and Garfunkel spoken word" led me to this: [The Break Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8gH_EuNaNk)

Comment: Checked "The Break Up", "Old Friends" and "Silent Night (7 O'Clock News)". It is none of these. These have talking but they seem to be real talking. The song was more like "a rock; a bridge; running water..." but the list was longer and a bunch of things back to back. It may of actually be sung too, I'm not sure if there was instrumentals behind the talking and/or singing. I referenced the things above, which I think "rock" was mentioned, but not sure about the others. I always found bridge over troubled water when I've searched in the past, but that is not the song i'm looking for.

Comment: I just realized, that I haven't considered the fact that it might either of them on their own... I'm going to have to do some searching based on them individually too.

Comment: So I looked through all the lyric links of http://www.azlyrics.com/p/paulsimon.html and http://www.azlyrics.com/s/simongarfunkel.html and did not find what I'm looking for. Does anyone know of a more official site for S&G?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possibly Art Garfunkel's solo rendition of the bossa nova classic [The Waters of March](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrmcSJGvz4s)?

Comment: I didn't realize Art had done a version, but the lyrics put me in mind of "Waters of March" and a simple search uncovered his version.  BTW there are much better versions of the same song, IMHO.  It's one of the great classics of Brazilian jazz.

Answer (score 2):

None of Simon and Garfunkle's songs were pure nonsense, but several were pretty random.  Here are a couple of top prospects for the song you remember:

[Punky's Dilemma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsnlMqraDvQ) --a quirky, surreal stream-of-consciousness narrative that starts with a fantasy of being a breakfast cereal:

[A Simple Desultory Philippic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOvs3rCFI2A) --a vicious Dylan parody.

Comment: Thanks Chris. These are good examples, but not the song I'm looking for.

Comment: Too bad, I was betting on Punky's too. I'm afraid I'm ou of ideas.